# Jqplot Bar Chart; I need to have mouseover on a yaxis label show a tooltip

Tags: jqplot

I am using a jqplot bar chart and looking for a way to have a tooltip on mouseover of the y axis labels. The customer wants paragraph labels I want to have short labels then allow mouseover to get the full text. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use your short labels array as parameters for axes.yaxis.ticks option, then set the **title** attribute for every y axis label element(class is *jqplot-yaxis-tick*). Make sure to set the z-index css for y axis label div(class is *jqplot-yaxis*) so that you can get the tooltip when mouseovered.